# How to make firefox use notifyOSD?

Tags: firefox, notify-osd

I have a computer that has 10.04 installed on it. When I download something off the internet, NotifyOSD displays to say the download is complete (Firefox is using NotifyOSD).

I'm using 11.04 on another computer. When Firefox finishes downloading something it displays the "Firefox  notifier" that pops up in the lower right corner of the monitor to tell me the download is complete (firefox is NOT using NotifyOSD).

Can this be fixed? I'd like for Firefox to use NotifyOSD on 11.04 like it is on 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

The notify-osd functionality was provided by the third-party extension `xul-ext-notify`.

The firefox maintainers have [discussed this on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/742475).

In summary - the maintainers of `xul-ext-notify` looks like they have abandoned the project.  Canonical themselves will not support this integration.  Thus unless someone steps forward, this capability will not be included in natty or future versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: :( Why won't Canonical support this integration? I LOVED the NotifyOSD notifications of when a Download completed.

Comment: 'fraid I cant answer that - I dont work for canonical.  The only thing I can suggest is to file this question on the canonical developers mailing list.

Comment: I've added my own two cents worth at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/742475. (A note for the new to Launchpad: don't post "me too" comments unless you have something additional to add to the conversation. Just find the link at the top that says how many people it affects and add yourself if the issue affects you.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a modified version of Chromify-OSD, a Javascript that lets Firefox use notify-osd for notifications.

1. Download [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/748/addon-748-latest.xpi?src=ss) for Firefox.
2. Download the [Chromify-OSD script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/chromify-osd/greasemonkey/view/head:/chromify-osd.user.js)
3. Download the [NPAPI plugin](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chromify-osd-team/chromify-osd/npapi/download/head:/npchromifyosd.so-20110107192915-qos956zq3ubhnprh-1/npchromifyosd.so) and copy them to your `~/.mozilla/plugins/` folder and restart the browser.
4. After all that, run the following command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.1
   ```

Now, Firefox should be using notify-OSD for notifications.

Related question:

- [How to make Firefox use chromify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103861/how-to-make-firefox-use-chromify-osd/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [GNotifier](https://github.com/mkiol/GNotifier) but use it at your own risk, as its' [not approved](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnotifier/) by Mozilla for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can install xul-ext-notify as mentioned by fossfreedom, but it is not supported and you might have to install the addon compatibility reporter to get it to work in later versions of Firefox.