# How to make Firefox use chromify-osd?

Tags: firefox, notify-osd

I understand that Chrome has [chromify-osd](http://chromify-osd.com/), an extension that lets it use notify-osd for notifications. Is it possible to customize it such that it works for Firefox as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a script made by Marco Ceppi and modified by George Edison that allows Firefox to use Notify-OSD.

For Firefox to use Notify-OSD, you need to have [Greasemonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/748/addon-748-latest.xpi?src=ss) installed in Firefox. After that, you need to download [this script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/chromify-osd/greasemonkey/view/head:/chromify-osd.user.js). 
You also have to download [NPAPI plugin](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chromify-osd-team/chromify-osd/npapi/download/head:/npchromifyosd.so-20110107192915-qos956zq3ubhnprh-1/npchromifyosd.so) and copy them to your `~/.mozilla/plugins/` folder and restart the browser.

After all that, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.1
```

You now should have Firefox using Notify-OSD for displaying notifications.

Comment: Is the reboot necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no.

A slightly longer answer is that Chrome extensions will not work with Firefox, and vice-versa. You can however look for a Firefox extension that does more or less the same job, but I haven't heard of one similar to chromify-osd.